# vue3 isCustomElement is detecting component as a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue-component, web-component, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to get a webcomponent working with vitejs.

component I am trying to use:
https://www.webcomponents.org/element/input-knob

I did as describe in the docs.

install and setup `@vitejs/plugin-vue`

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/plugin-vue#vitejsplugin-vue-

initiate the customelement in config. ( I also tried simply putting the custom element in main.js
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1312

vite.config.js

```js
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
export default {
  plugins: [
    VitePWA(),
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: tag => tag === 'input-knob'
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

still getting the same warning :frowning:

```js
app.config.isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('input-')

console.log(app.config.isCustomElement('input-knob'))
```

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'

const app = createApp(App);

app.config.isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('input-')

console.log(app.config.isCustomElement('input-knob'))
app.mount('#app')
```

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: input-knob

the log returns true, so I am not sure where the problem actually is.

Comment: Got also some problems webcomponents but with webpack. Which vue version do you use? Did you log also the vite part?  compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: tag => tag === 'input-knob'
        }

Comment: It is the latest version.

(i did not add the vite config)

```js

  "dependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.1.4",
    "@vueuse/core": "^4.2.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.4",
    "vite": "^1.0.0-rc.13",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "^0.5.4"
  }
}


```

Comment: How do I log vite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was vite version. Pushing it to vite2 fixes this.

`"vite": "^2.0.5"`